# start Selenium chrome driver minimized (or equivalent)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, undetected-chromedriver

I'm making a web scraping program, but to keep from being blocking by anti-scraping software I gotta keep the driver out of headless mode. sometimes I also need to restart the driver to clear the cookies, so whenever it opens back up I minimize it immediately, but it still gets in the way of whatever Im doing for about a second, and this program runs for hours so its incredibly annoying

Im thinking theres probably something I can add like `driver.add_option("start in minimized")` or `driver.add_option("start in off screen")` (equivalent to `driver.set_window_position(-2000,0)` but before the driver opens

does anyone know of an options setting I can add for this?

heres what my current code looks like, though this is more of a feature question than a bug fixing problem

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc

def start_uc():
    '''opens a UC chrome driver with prefered settings'''
    options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    # just some options passing in to skip annoying popups
    options.add_argument('--no-first-run --no-service-autorun --password-store=basic')
    return uc.Chrome(options=options)

driver = start_uc()
driver.minimize_window()

for item in list:
    #scrape item info

    if blocked from page:
        driver.close()
        driver = start_uc()
        driver.minimize_window()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such option / capability.
You can set `driver` to start maximized with

```py
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
```

But **there is no such option** as `options.add_argument("start-minimized")`.
As you mentioned, you can minimize the driver screen immediately **after** it's creating with `driver.set_window_position(-2000,0)` but, again, this will be applied only after the `driver` is opened.

Comment: that explains why I couldn't find anything about how to do this while searching.
thankyou